# How to assign a class to all links starting with a hash?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery (or plain JavaScript) I want target all links that start with a hash (`#`), meaning all links that jump to a location on the current page.

Then I want to assign the class `in-page-link` to those links.

Comment: Did you do any research, or attempt a solution yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```
$("a[href^='#']").addClass("in-page-link");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href^="#"]').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('in-page-link');
});
```

Comment: No reason for `each`.

Comment: Either you should remove `.each` or use `this.className += ' in-page-link'`.